# Dot product between two vectors and its independence from reference frame

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, education, products

I found in the equation (2) [here](http://crrl.poly.edu/522/rotation_matrices.pdf) the dot product between two vectors and the author said that it is independent from the reference frame.
What does it mean in this particular case?

The notation is: $x^i_j$ where x is the unit vector of the frame j when written in terms of the fram i.

Maybe:

$$x_1 . x_0 = x^1_1 . x_0^0 = x_1^0 . x_0^0 = x_1^1 . x_0^1 = x_1^1 . x_0^0$$

?
Can you show me the meaning of the above sentence by starting from the dot product $x_1 . x_0$ please?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: When the author says the dot product is independent of reference frame, that means that it's something which is well-defined in the vectors themselves, and not some arithmetic operation of whatever coordinates we give them (even though that's how we most often calculate it).

Comment: Hello @Arthur, can you read my comment to Ofek Gillon please?

Comment: You should be careful to distinguish between the _dot product_ of two coordinate tuples, which is very much reference-frame dependent, and an _inner product_ of two vectors, which is not.

Comment: Hello @amd, can you explain your comment with references or examples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you and I are at the same position in space but I am standing upside down, then any vector you see as $(x,y,z)$ I see as $(x,y,-z)$. It is the same vector but in different reference frames. The dot product has a physical meaning, so when you take 2 vectors and apply the dot product you should get the same result I would get taking the same 2 vectors (but standing on my head). In this example it is quite obvious to prove this:

If you have two vectors $(x_1 ,y_1 , z_1) , (x_2 , y_2 , z_2)$ so I will see them as $(x_1 ,y_1 , -z_1) , (x_2 , y_2 , -z_2) $ and it is easy to see that we both "measure" the same dot product because in the multiplication of the z coordinates the minuses will cancel out.

This is also true for someone tilting his head - the coordinates of vectors will maybe messed up but for any two vectors, $u\cdot v$ is invariant for any reference frame.

The physical meaning of the dot product is $u\cdot v = |u| |v| \cos \alpha $ where $|u|,|v|$ is the length of the vectors (which doesn't depend on reference frame) and $\alpha$ is the angle between them - again, something that doesn't change.

Comment: Hello @OfekGillon, thus in my case I can write the equation in this way (both unit vectors are always written in terms of the same reference frame): $x_1 . x_0 = x_1^1 . x_0^1 = x_1^0 . x_0^0$?

Comment: the answer to my comment is yes. I reached this conclusion thanks to your answer.

Comment: Actually no, if you have 2 vectors $x_1^i , x_2^i$ which are presented in a different reference frame as $ x'_1^i , x_2'^i $ then the equality that holds is:
$$ \sum_i x_1^i x_2^i = \sum_i x_1'^i x_2'^i $$

Comment: Hello @OfekGillon, it seems that I wrote the same thing in the comment. Can you tell me what is the difference please?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your notation. I thought the terms you wrote are all scalar quantities.

Comment: Hi @OfekGillon I used a bad notation; they are vectors and the dot is the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is very strange. The usual treatment of the problem is as follows. Suppose in one referene frame two vectors are $x,\,y$, so their dot product is $x^T gy$ for some matrix $g$. (For the usual dot product, $g$ is the identity matrix; but I've generalised because your use of "reference frame" suggests an interest in relativity, for which $g$ is chosen differently.) A coordinate transformation updates the vectors respectively to $\Lambda x,\,\Lambda y$, with $\Lambda^T g\Lambda=g$. (For $g=I$, this simplifies to $\Lambda^T\Lambda=I$; such $\Lambda$ are called orthogonal matrices.) Thus $(\Lambda x)^Tg(\Lambda y)=x^T(\Lambda^T g\Lambda)y=x^T gy$, establishing invariance.

Comment: Hi @J.G. I agree with you, the notation used here http://crrl.poly.edu/522/rotation_matrices.pdf is so strange. I know what the invariance of dot product mean. My goal is to understand its application in the above particular case.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I think you just need to repeat the above matrix calculation in components.